# ReadAllLines not reading a line with file path correctly

Tags: c#

I'm using "System.IO.File.ReadAllLines" (WinForm). everything works well until I reach the following line in the file:

```
  <rootfile full-path="Kerp_9780553419412_epub3_opf_r1.opf" media-type="application/oebps-package+xml"/>
```

The program reads it as:

```
  <rootfile full-path=\"content.opf\" media-type=\"application/oebps-package+xml\"/>"   string
```

This is the code:

```
string[] containerXML = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(wrkPath + @"\META-INF\container.xml"); // read file;

int i = 0;
int IndexOfOPFLocation = containerXML[i].IndexOf("full-path");

while (i < containerXML.Count() && IndexOfOPFLocation == -1)
{
    i++;
    IndexOfOPFLocation = containerXML[i].IndexOf("full-path");
} 

string OPFLocation = containerXML[i].Substring(IndexOfOPFLocation + 10, containerXML[i].IndexOf('"', IndexOfOPFLocation + 11) - IndexOfOPFLocation);

return OPFLocation;
```

I tried various ways of using the @ sign. None worked.

I assume the problem is related to the fact that there is a file path in the line. But I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: Why do you think it's wrong?

Comment: Coz I get this "\"content.opf\"" istead of this: "Kerp_9780553419412_epub3_opf_r1.opf"

The two lines are different

Comment: You say you use `ReadAllLines()` yet it's nowhere in your code snippets...

Comment: @stickybit added

Comment: I *strongly* suspect that it's reading it absolutely fine, but you're looking at the string in the debugger. That escapes the string to show it to you. Write the string out to the console, or look at the individual characters in the debugger, and you'll see that the backslashes aren't actually there.

Comment: That said, I'd *strongly* encourage you to start using XML APIs to read the HTML rather than using low-level string operations.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Oh, I hadn't spotted that. I strongly suspect that's a diagnostic mistake and the OP is looking at the wrong file or something similar. I'd only spotted the backslash part, which I'm sure is just misunderstanding what the debugger is showing.

Comment: Are you sure you are reading the correct file? Is your wrkPath relative or absolute? If it is relative, make sure your working directory matches your expectations.

Comment: @Lesiak I'm sure it's the right file since every other line in the file is read Ok

Comment: @MennyBarzilay Well, are you sure it's the correct _line_ as well? In other words, are you sure there isn't another line (before the one you're expecting) which _also_ contains "full-path"? Moreover, can you post the contents of the file (into your question if it's not too long or, otherwise, on something like pastebin.com)?

Answer (score 2):

Using string operations on XML will fail sooner or later.
You will need to learn XmlDocument or XDocument if you want to read epub's etc.

Let's replace all of this:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(wrkPath + @"\META-INF\container.xml");
var ns = doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
var OPFLocation = doc.Descendants(ns + "rootfile").Single().Attribute("full-path").Value;
```

don't forget to prefix that with wrkPath  again.

Answer (score 1):

There was indeed a bug in another part of the code that passed the wrong file into processing.

I cannot erase the question. Thanks for everyone. Especially @Lesiak that made me look again.